# ruby rack rpc server/client example

Tags: ruby, xml-rpc, rack

I have next code

```
require 'rack/rpc'

class Server < Rack::RPC::Server
  def hello_world
    "Hello, world!"
  end


  rpc 'hello_world' => :hello_world

end


server = Server.new
use Rack::RPC::Endpoint, server
run server
```

script name is server.ru

I'm starting server with command

```
thin start -R server.ru 


>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Also client example

```
require "xmlrpc/client"

# Make an object to represent the XML-RPC server.
server = XMLRPC::Client.new( "0.0.0.0", "/rpc", 3000)
# Call the remote server and get our result
result = server.call("hello_word")


puts result
```

next command gives me exception

```
ruby client.rb 
client.rb:414:in `call': Method hello_word missing or wrong number of parameters! (XMLRPC::FaultException)
    from client.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Why hello_word can't be found? Thank you.

Comment: what is the point of changing your original question, so that the actual problem isn't in there any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a typo. You are calling `hello_word` instead of `hello_world` try:

```
result = server.call("hello_world")
```

this should do the trick. I do not think that you can start the server with the `run server` in your Rackup file. Of course you need a `run` statement in your config.ru but running an instance of your server class is pointless, because it doesn't even have a `call` method. In practice you would mount another application there, for example:

```
require 'builder'
require 'rack/rpc'

class Server < Rack::RPC::Server
  def hello_world
    "Hello, world from RPC Server!"
  end 

  rpc 'hello_world' => :hello_world
end

class MyApplication
  def call(env)
    [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["Hello world from MyApplication!"]]
  end 
end

use Rack::RPC::Endpoint, Server.new
run MyApplication.new
```

I also needed to include the `builder` gem in order to get this to work.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if your problem is solved ;)

Comment: Can you tell how can I use parameters in methods, or they map automaticly ?

Comment: You simply do `call(method_name, arg1, arg2, …)`. This page has some examples: http://www.fantasy-coders.de/ruby/xmlrpc4r/client.html

Comment: thanks , maybe you can give some words on my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796363/scalable-xml-rpc-service